# Syntax error in SQL update query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to update a table in MSAccess whose fields have data type of 'Text'. But when I run the code it shows sysntax error in UPDATE statement. Here is my vb code:

Dim user As String
        Dim password As String
        Dim dtT As New DataTable

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    user = Me.TextBox1.Text
    password = Me.TextBox2.Text


    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Try
        Dim daA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM adlogin WHERE password='" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "'", cnn)

        ' MsgBox("STUDENT SAVED!!", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight)

        daA.Fill(dtT)
        Me.DG1.DataSource = dtT


        'password = DG1.Item(0, 0).Value
        'ss1 = DG1.Item(1, 0).Value

        If user = DG1.Item(1, 0).Value And password = DG1.Item(0, 0).Value Then


            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE adlogin SET password ='" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE user =" & Me.TextBox1.Text
            System.Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)

            Dim result = MsgBox("Change Administrator password!!! Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

            If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("PassWord Changed", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight)
                Panel1.Hide()
            End If


        Else
            MsgBox("INVALID PASSWORD", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

        End If
        cnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("INVALID PASSWORD " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use string concatenation to create SQL commands. Use always PARAMETERS
This will resolve two problems: 
Single quote inside your strings, but, the most important thing, avoid [SQL Injection Attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand 
user = Me.TextBox1.Text 
password = Me.TextBox2.Text 

If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then 
    cnn.Open() 
End If 

Try 
    Dim daA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM adlogin WHERE `password` =?", cnn) 
    daA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
    daA.Fill(dtT) 
    Me.DG1.DataSource = dtT 


    If user = DG1.Item(1, 0).Value And password = DG1.Item(0, 0).Value Then 
        cmd.Connection = cnn 
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE adlogin SET `password` = ? WHERE `user` = ?" 
        Dim result = MsgBox("Change Administrator password!!! Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) 
        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Me.TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
            MsgBox("PassWord Changed", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight) 
            Panel1.Hide() 
        End If 
    Else 
        MsgBox("INVALID PASSWORD", MsgBoxStyle.Critical) 
    End If 
    cnn.Close() 
Catch ex As Exception 
    MsgBox("INVALID PASSWORD " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical) 
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space after the * on this line :

`Dim daA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM adlogin WHERE password='" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "'", cnn)`

to

`Dim daA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM adlogin WHERE password='" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "'", cnn)`

You also need to put your variable between '

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE adlogin SET password ='" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE user =" & Me.TextBox1.Text`

to

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE adlogin SET password ='" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE user ='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'"`

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

```
SELECT *FROM adlogin etc...
        ^---no space

UPDATE adlogin [..snip...] WHERE user =" & Me.TextBox1.Text
                                       ^---- is "user" a numeric field? needs quotes if not.
```

Comment: Whatever is numeric or not, should always have quotes to protect against injection.

Comment: quotes don't do anything to prevent injection. proper escaping/sanitization/parameterization do that. If you can inject data, you easily inject a quote.